# Anychart Android Java export chart as SVG or PNG in specific local folder

Tags: java, android, anychart, anychart-8.2

I was trying to create and save an image with AnyChart for an android application. This image is created without being rendered since the idea is to use the data from a vector to generate the image and save it on the phone's memory. I am using Java for programming the android application.

I have been testing the ".saveAsPng()" and ".saveAsSVG()" functions from the Anychart Library but there has been no success... I don't receive an error but I don't get the image either... and I don't know exactly how to proceed...

I tried to follow this guideline (https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Server-Side_Rendering) but as I said, I haven't succeeded in generating and saving the file.

This is the code that I have been using:

```
private class CustomDataEntry2 extends ValueDataEntry {
    CustomDataEntry2(double x, Number value) {
        super(x, value);
    }
}
```

_

```
List<DataEntry> dataLateral = new ArrayList<>();
for (int p=0; p<DataX.size();p++) {
      dataLateral.add(new CustomDataEntry2(DataY.get(p), DataX.get(p)));          
}

AnyChartView anyChartViewLateral = new com.anychart.AnyChartView(this);
APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(anyChartViewLateral);
anyChartViewLateral.setProgressBar(new ProgressBar(this));
Polar polarLateralImage = AnyChart.polar();
polarLateralImage.startAngle(90);
Linear xScaleLateral = Linear.instantiate();
xScaleLateral.minimum(-180).maximum(180);
xScaleLateral.ticks().interval(90);
polarLateralImage.xScale(xScaleLateral);

Line polarSeriesLine = polarLateralImage.line(dataLateral);
polarSeriesLine.closed(false).markers(true);
polarSeriesLine.markers().size(3);

polarLateralImage.autoRedraw(true);
anyChartViewLateral.setChart(polarLateralImage);

polarLateralImage.saveAsPng(400,400,0.3,"testImage.png");
```

Could anyone tell me what am I missing or what amb I doing wrong? I know I might be asking too much, but if it were possible, I would be happy if someone could provide a code snippet that works.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the AnyChart Android native library doesn't support exporting features, it was no implemented yet.